# Autolayout constraint mismatch In UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitableview

Create simple application for dynamic cell height.

I have Custom `UITableViewCell` and in that I have some controls. I have fixed the constraint of all the controls. Tableview not displaying any error after constraint set. Tableview runtime cell height is ok, but when I check the console log it gives me error as given below.

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-06-08 17:54:22.184177+0530 Test[46461:306448] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286680 UILabel:0x7fe86bd1c4e0'Label'.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286810 V:|-(14)-[UILabel:0x7fe86bd1c4e0'Label']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe86bd1c220 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286860 V:[UILabel:0x7fe86bd1c4e0'Label']-(15)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe86bd1c220 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286cc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe86bd1c220.height == 49   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286680 UILabel:0x7fe86bd1c4e0'Label'.height == 50   (active)>
```

**Bellow is my TableView and its constraint.**
[image]

**Bellow is my TableView Code**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString * strAction = arrActionList[indexPath.row];
    if ([strAction isEqualToString:@"More"]) {
        cell.lblActionHeight.constant = 50;
    }
    else{
        cell.lblActionHeight.constant = 20;
    }
    cell.lblAction.text = strAction;
    [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you use constrain in tableview cellforRowatindexpath just use autolayout

Comment: Whenever we try to change the constraint programmatically in the table view, the log prints these kinds of warning. But do you achieve your expected result?

Comment: if Action name is 'more' then label height is 50.

Comment: @PraveenKumar tableview cell display as i expected,
but only print log in console.

Comment: @Lalji check my answer it supports you alot.

Comment: If you use UITableViewAutomaticDimension you have to set an estimatedRowHeight as well. Try overriding `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` (you can really use any value, but a value has to be set)

Comment: @Lalji The reason it gives is that you are acting against the auto layout principles. Manipulating auto layout constraints manually gives this kind of warning.

Answer (score 0):

**Meaning of console log:**

```
your_cell_height(79) = top(14) + lbl_ht(50) + bottom(15) // from storyboard
```

But cell for row

your_cell_height be 79 and according to it tablecell is managing so

```
your_cell_height(49) = top(14) + lbl_ht(20) + bottom(15) // from CellForRow Method
```

So 49 not equal to 79 thats why there is constraints conflicts.

**Resolve.**

remove bottom constraint and try.

If you have any specified cell layout then specific, according it i will suggest.

> edit

add your label in a view with contraints : **(L,R,T,B) = (0,0,0,0)** and **height = 79** with relationship `less than equal to`

Give label same constraints as you give here.

Add Below Delegate Methods

cellForHeight

```
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and  estimateHeight

```
return 79
```

Comment: after remove bottom constraint all cell are same height and cell not display as i expected,

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to give height constraint,you should give top,bottom,leading,trailing.

If you need height constraint, then you should give (leading,trailing,top,height) or (leading,trailing,centerY,height)

Make sure you return the proper height in the heightForRow method.

You need to specify estimated row height if you want to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

In your case, estimatedRow height is the exact row height in the IB.